# How to implement distibuted DB on Hyperledger Fabric (GDPR)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We are building a solution and we are modeling a network using Fabric and Composer

Regarding "not" storing any personal data (GDPR complience) on the blockchain, we would like to hash/map the personal data so that a GUID och Hash is stored in the Ledger instead (Anonymized data)

Does Hyperledger provide any solution to solve this kind of issues (ie a distributed DB that is around the ledger peers for example?)

Or is this something that is needed to be implemented outside the Hypeledger network topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Fabric v1.1, you would need to provide the database yourself and then just write the hashes to the blockchain as normal transactions.  There are people who do this today for database records as well as for documents (store the document outside and just write the hash and metadata to the blockchain).

In Fabric v1.1, there is an experimental featured known as "private data".  With this feature, the actual state is kept local to the peers in a private state database and is not included in the actual blockchain itself.  The ledger actually contains hashes of the key and value.

There are new chaincode APIs (Get/PutPrivateData) which are used to do this automatically for you.  You can then either delete the data manually or use the DeletePrivateState function in chaincode to delete the actual records (the hash will stay on the channel ledger).

This feature is experimental in v1.1 so you will need to build the peer from source with `-tags experimental`.

Since this feature is experimental, it is not currently supported in Composer.

We will be hardening the feature as part of the 1.2 release which is under development

Comment: thank you very Intresting. We’ll definitely check this feature. Meanwhile, could you point us in the right direction regarding the pre1.1 way? Is it just a middleware function in the client app before sending the transaction proposal?